# Defining a new optional parameter to my RouteConfig table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been using the default route table as follow:-

```
public class RouteConfig
    {

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        { routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
          routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            ); } }
```

And on the Shared view I have the following Html.actionlink, as part of my breadcrumb to reference the current page :-

```
@Html.ActionLink(aoutput == "Index" ? "Home" : aoutput , action, controller )
```

Which will work well as long as the parameter in the URL is id, but on some action methods they accept a parameter named customername as follow:-

```
…./Customer/ManageCustom?customerName=name123
```

But the Html.ActionLink will fail to reference the customerName from the current URL, since inside my routing map there is no reference to the customerName parameter . so can anyone advice accordingly ?
Regards

**EDIT**

The ManageCustom Action method looks like:-

```
public ActionResult ManageCustom(string customerName)
       {

          //code goes here
           return View( customAssets);

       }
```

Comment: Could you show your ManageCustom action?

Comment: i have added it my my original post..

Comment: It would be nice if you let us know where are you getting aoutput, action and controller variables for ActionLink.

Answer (score 1):

The url doesn't much to controller action you specified. Try to change `ManageCustom` to `ManageCustomAsset` in it and you will see that it works fine.

Also it should work if you change action name or use [Action Name attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) with value `ManageCustom`. Example of ActionName attribute:

```
[ActionName("ManageCustom")]
public ActionResult ManageCustomAsset(string customerName) 
{
    //code goes here
    return View( customAssets);
}
```

Your default route expects you to put optional id to resource string, it will look like this:
`/Customer/ManageCustom/123`, where 123 - is id.

But you are putting the parameters to action through query string, that's what goes after '?' sign and routing don't have any restrictions for this.

Comment: sorry i posted the wrong code, the action method name is ManageCustom. but still the customername will not be appended to the html.actionlink generated link ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused a little. So the problem with generating right link, with hiting right action with the url or with passing data from customerName paramater?

Comment: no the html.ActionLink , refer to the current page inside a breadcrumb, currently if the current page URL contains customername parameter, then clicking on the html.actionlink will generate a URL without the custoemrname inside it, unlike when the current URL contain an id ...

Comment: Where do get parameters for actionlink? What are the aoutput, action and controller contain?